# Docker ARG tricky behavior

Tags: docker, containers

Docker build tricky behavior:

Dockerfile

```
ARG php_version="7.2" 
ARG flavor="stretch" 

FROM php:${php_version}-fpm-${flavor} 

#ARG php_version="7.2" 
ENV php_v $php_version 
CMD echo $php_v
```

If you build it and run:

```
docker build -t args:1.0 .
docker run -it --name testargs args:1.0
```

Output is empty string instead of the expected "7.2"

But if the third ARG line is uncommented we get "7.2"

Why does it behave this way?

Comment: See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `FROM` in a Dockerfile represents a new build stage and an `ARG` declared before the `FROM` is not available for use in the newer build stages starting with another `FROM`.

To quote the relevant section of the [doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact):

> An ARG declared before a FROM is outside of a build stage, so it can’t
> be used in any instruction after a FROM.